Student sleeps in the class during the lecture
I'm a grad student and a lecturer of a section of a first year undergrad math course. This is my third year involved in teaching and this is first time something like this happened.
Last week, a student sitting in the front row fell asleep during my teaching. He breathed very heavily and was very distracting. I wasn't sure how to act and I didn't want to embarrass/scold him in front of everyone. Some other students noticed it, and I quietly, without others hearing it, asked a student behind to push him. He woke up and we continued like nothing happened.
Today it happened again and I got stressed and lost the flow of the argument during my teaching and got angry. But I kept my composure and "accidentally" touched him with the paper sheets as I passed by and he woke up.
I haven't talked with him about it, and I might ask a course chair for advice. But I feel very disrespected. Only tangentially related, but I'm not that boring, I get 90% very good anonymous feedback/review at the end of every semester.
After the class I mentioned it to two of his friends/classmates, as they also noticed it, and one of them giggled and said that he will tell him to sit in the back next time (this is not what I want though).
What is a good course of action? This is the US, and I'm a foreigner and if I act the way it is normal in my country, here it might be considered overly inappropriate and I don't want unnecessary tension.
UPD:
I like cag51 answer and will follow it in practice. Thank you all, but honestly, some of your reactions were hostile. I come from another culture and a notion of respect is very culture-dependent and don't always have a pragmatic rationale. And one of my problems was that it disturbed the lecture flow which affects subsequently other students experience. I came with a good will.
I don't assume any disrespect anymore, but the noise may still be disturbing so I will talk to him as gentle as possible about the noise. Also I will suggest him, in the case of personal troubles causing it, the help options provided by school.
UPD2:
Please don't respond explaining why sleeping is respectful or disrespectful. Respect is a social construct which depends on the culture but it seems you're assuming your culture to be universal. Since I live in the western world, I don't have a problem of following western social constructs.

Is attendence to classes mandatory in your setting or are students free to chose whether they attend?

This is the classic fallacy of humans to attribute other peoples actions to character flaws - you see a sleeping student and jump to the conclusion 'he sleeps because he disrespects me'. Statistically, it is much more likely to be attributed not to a very disrespectful character but to circumstances - he might be in the process of breaking up with a girlfriend, overwhelmed with studying until late into the night, sliding into a depressive episode, have a roommate that makes getting enough sleep hard. It's possible that he is disrespecting you, but that is not the most likely scenario.

Personally I don't get why you would ask such a question here. Surely the best course of action is to ask this question to your employer or other colleagues.

"...said that he will tell him to sit in the back next time (this is not what I want though)" Can you clarify why you don't want this, and what instead is your desired outcome?

The other people have added excellent reasons why someone might be regularly falling asleep. I can also add that several physical conditions can cause it, even for people who do not have caring responsibilities, etc.

When you present to senior colleages at the depatment or faculty seminar, they may also fall asleep. Also when visiting other universities on invitation to present. They do not disrespect you. They just get sleepy, even when coffee was provided before the seminar and even when they are interested in the topic. It just happens. Don't feel offended, it is not worth it.

@VladimirFГероямслава one of the committee members on my PhD defence not only fell asleep during my presentation, he snored. Even my family, sitting several rows behind, noticed.

Probably apocryphal story:  A student fell asleep and the professor yells to the guy next to the sleeper "Hey, wake up your friend".  The student responds, "No way.  You wake him up.  It was you who put him to sleep!"

I had a friend who worked night time job and could not help but to fall asleep in a class. He was a great person and studied well.

I was a decent student who cared about my classes, but I'm pretty sure I dozed off occasionally. Students work, they cram, they play games all night, etc.

"if I act the way it is normal in my country, here it might be considered overly inappropriate", what would you do in your country that would count as inappropriate in the US?

@quarague if it was my choice, then I would have made it non-mandatory. But there are quizzes that are set by course policy.

@Ivo I assumed that we are all colleagues in academia and needed a second opinion. It wasn't a rant.

@user2390246 I mean if he sleeps loudly in the back of the class, then it would be harder for me to reach unnoticeably and wake him up

@Torque "You see a sleeping student and jump to the conclusion 'he sleeps because he disrespects me'"- I don't think it's necessary to jump to any conclusion. Sleeping is an inherently disrespectful action. Now, if OP had said "this student does not respect me," that would be a conclusion that could either be true or false. But the statement that "this student behaved disrespectfully" is not really debatable. For example, imagine a code of conduct or student handbook that listed examples of disrespectful behavior. It would be reasonable to include sleeping in class in that list.

Are you from East Asia (China, Korea, Japan)? In the US, this is almost certainly not a deliberate act of disrespect towards the teacher and more likely just a very tired student who couldn't help falling asleep.

@user182601 I'm from East Europe.

@user1172763 "Sleeping is an inherently disrespectful action" ??? citation needed

@user1172763 this is moving more towards being chat; you are falling for the same fallacy I described. You don't know why the student fell asleep, for all you know, it could be a neurological issue. You are just jumping to the conclusion that the only reason it possibly could happen is because he has no respect for the teacher, which simply isn't true, and with the student choosing front row imo isn't even the most probable case (most probable being 'not enough sleep due to studying/working to afford classes'). Hanlons razor comes to mind.

@AaronF One widely-listed synonym for "disrespectful" is "impolite" i.e. "not polite." It shouldn't be controversial to say that sleeping in class is not polite. It's just a matter of knowing what "disrespectful" actually means. Another definition I found was "showing a lack of respect or courtesy." There's a reason they included "or courtesy" in there.


I feel very disrespected

Don't be. It sounds like when you wake him up, he tries to remain awake and pretend like nothing happened. So, I don't think he is intentionally falling asleep as a signal of disapproval. Rather, my guess is that he was up late and then your classroom is warm and you are lecturing and his eyelids feel heavy and next thing he knows he's waking up and wondering whether anyone noticed. Been there.
Also, don't discount the possibility that he is tired because he is working full-time while going to school, or caring for an elderly relative, or taking too many classes, or something else along those lines. Even if he is just staying up late partying, it's still admirable that he tries to attend your class rather than just skipping.

After the class I mentioned to two of his friends/classmates about this

I am not sure what context this was in, but in general it makes me a little nervous. Gossiping about the student with the student's friends is rarely appropriate.

I might ask for a course chair for advice...What is a good course of action?

If the student's sleeping is disruptive, you should gently take action. For example, gently ask the student to sit in the back.
After you've eliminated any disruption, you have wide latitude on how to handle this. Asking your course chair for advice is a very good idea. Doing nothing is a perfectly fine choice. If you want to have a gentle conversation with the student, fine, but tread lightly. I strongly recommend against showing anger or otherwise being harsh with the student; that does not seem to be called for here.

"I don't think he is intentionally falling asleep as a signal of disapproval. " So much this. I've fallen asleep during perfectly fine lectures, despite sitting there fidgeting desperately trying to keep awake because life got in the way  (absolutely no parties and/or drinking involved). What really helped were lecturers who at the half way mark, had a short break, encouraged everyone to get up and opened the windows.

@Marianne013 I've seen senior staff fall asleep in colloquia (in one case, the current and 2 former heads of department, but I couldn't have called that talk "perfectly fine").  As you hint, warm air doesn't help, neither does a high level of CO₂ from everyone breathing.

What @Marianne013 commented is really probably the most important action the lecturer can take: make sure to have breaks and do whatever they can to keep the room aired out and not too warm (not too cold either, of course). That will benefit not only the one student who falls asleep, but also all the other students who manage to stay awake, but don’t take in very much because the heat and lack of oxygen is making them drowsy.

If a lack of respect were the cause of his sleeping in your class, I don’t see why he would bother to attend at all. I imagine he has available to him  more comfortable options for napping.

Going to someone's class just to disrespect them by sleeping would take quite some power of will and dedication. I'd be impressed

When I was in graduate school, we had visiting professors give talks about their work. These lectures were usually after lunch, the lights were dimmed and the lecture included a slide show, the seats were comfortable ... zzzz. Many of the students, including me, would fall asleep. No disrespect was intended, and the lecturer either didn't notice or pretended not to.

@PaulTanenbaum My initial thought wasn't that lack of respect was the cause of sleeping, but sleeping was the cause of disrespect. I don't think that anymore though as I've updated it in my question above.

@anonym just to give you another example, in case it helps to hear from the student's perspective: I have unintentionally fallen asleep in lectures I was really interested in! I had issues with uncontrollable sleepiness as an undergrad. I sometimes tried to force myself to stay awake by sitting in the front row - it didn't help. I have fallen asleep during 1-1 conversations.

If you talk to the student you could ask if there's any accommodations that would help them stay awake - for example is there somewhere they can sit where they can stand and move around a little if that would help them?

Many teachers know the risk of giving classes after lunch time. You should suddenly raise your voice for no reason.. except that then, the students have then more blood in the stomach than in the brain :)

One can be disrespectful unintentionally or simply by not caring. Regardless of how OP interprets the student's intentions, the student is being disruptive and careless. Showing respect in class requires some level of active attention, and its OK to gently remind the students of this

@Wastrel That's an advice I've heard several times, but that many lecturers don't seem to know about: if you want your audience to be awake and in the best disposition to understand you, keep the windows open and the lights on, even if you have slides! Slides are no excuse to put everyone to sleep!

@Stef I agree with that. Unfortunately, though, in modern buildings the windows can't be opened. But there's no reason to dim the lights for a slideshow, the screen should be bright enough.


I feel very disrespected

I will give you two perspectives to maybe change your mind
The Course I was Waiting For The Whole Year
When I was in my 4th year of physics, a lecturer was about to give THE course I was waiting for. I was extremely interested in the topic (that would lead to my PhD later) and could not wait for the class to start.
In the first minutes I felt extremely tired and actually fell asleep. I woke up when the course was done. I was beyond desperation. I had no idea why I slept - I think this was paradoxally the stress and the anticipation.
A few years later I went to the prof (who became a friend) and told him about that. he told me he saw me and was rather surprised because he knew how interested I was.
Where I Realize That My Friend Has Narcolepsy
A friend of mine suddenly fell asleep during a course, several times. It was rather funny because she would wake up when some words were pronounced by the prof (and only these).
She told me she has narcolepsy and since she was a very good friend, we of course experimented with other friends on her when she was asleep checking which guitar chords would wake her up. She ended up publishing a paper on that :)

This was my first thought as well. A number of sleep-related medical conditions can cause these sorts of symptoms, and many can be exacerbated by (e.g.) early morning classes.  The student may not even be aware that such conditions even exist. If this becomes a pattern, it might be kind to gently suggest (in private) that the student asks a doctor about it. If it really is a medical issue, hopefully it can be treated before they sleep through something critical like an exam.

@bta in the case of my friend it was not treatable (at least easily - the side effects were not good). She has to live with that (and cannot work in dangerous conditions or drive). At least in her case she falls asleep like a "normal" person would do when being really tired, without danger to herself (it's not like she falls on the ground - rather she falls asleep and lays her head down). It's annoying like hell because she tends to have these bursts when she gets excited (she intermittently slept through a party I was throwing and was not happy at all but it ultimately ended very well for her

Depending on their financial situation, many students have to work besides taking classes, which might be resulting in them not gettin enough sleep. Other issues can make their life stressfull as well. With young people being young people, excessive partying might equally be a possibility.
I am pretty sure the student does not come to class to sleep and likewise, he is probably not falling asleep because of your teaching, but because he is tired when coming to class and has a hard time staying awake, no matter the content.
Instead of taking things personally, you could try talking to the student alone after class, along the lines of, "I don't want to embarras you, but you have fallen asleep in my class several times now - is everything ok?" Like this, you make him (and him alone) aware that you have noticed without assuming malice or bad behavior from the student.

that sounds like a good question for an email, thanks

@anonym I believe it would be much better to ask him in person

@WoJ it depends on a person. For example, I prefer to communicate sensitive topics via email with outside of my closely trusted group, so that I have more time to think how to respond. Others would want to speak in person to follow better non-verbal aspect of a communication.

@anonym yes of course it depends on the person, but having a direct interaction for such a personal thing would be, again in my opinion (and my culture (French), something to take into account as well), better conveyed in person so that it does not sound bureaucratic and formal.

Alternative Perspective:
As an undergraduate engineering student, I found that I didn't learn in the same way as other students. Somehow, I was(am) wired differently. (Neurodivergent?) That is, I didn't learn very well if I sat and looked at the instruction and took notes.
My grades improved when I found a method that worked for me:

Two days before class, I would skim the text.
The day before class, I would read the text attentively.
On the day of class, I would sit in the front row, and sleep the entire lecture with my head in the pages of the text, on the content to be covered.
The day after class, I would take detailed notes from the text.

So that was the most effective way for me to learn. Once I figured this out, I did it for every class in every course. Other students asked "why not sleep at home?" I would respond that while I am sleeping, some part of me listens to the instruction. And this sleep-listening was much more effective for me then awake-listening. (I would jerk awake if I sleep-heard the word "midterm")
So this university student:

Pays tuition to attend your class
Shows up for class

Perhaps they are like me, and they need to learn in a different way. I suggest having an open mind and letting them do what works for them.
I always sat/slept in the front center of the class, as close as possible to the instructor. However, I didn't snore loudly, and made sure not to disrupt class. If they are loud, or are actually disrupting the class, I suggest asking them to sleep off to the side.

Yes, some of my instructors would joke with me about it. Yes, these were large sized lecture classes. I was in the US.

+1 - have taught someone who learned like this - they absorbed information like a sponge while in a zen doze but really struggled if forced awake. After they demonstrated a reliable ability to ace review questions mostly left them to it. Whatever learning was going on did however stop if they went fully to sleep to the point of snoring, so at their request would poke them awake if that happened.

@GremlinWranger That's awesome. I'm not alone!

The subconscious captures. it can be put to use.

Many mentioned that: Maybe they work night shifts to fund their studies?
As long as they are not antagonistic, it's their responsibility to decide how to use their time. They pay the fees, if they do not take advantage of the service they pay for, it's on them. At least they have the intention to come to your lecture (I assume it is not compulsory to attend, which would be, anyway, a dumb rule at academic level).
So clearly, they want to be in the lecture. A prof I know regularly fell asleep in the department seminars. At question time, he woke up. After many show-off irrelevant questions, he would be usually the one to ask the one that hit the nail on the head. Who knows, maybe the student has a half-conscious way of absorbing information?
Now, if the student sleeping is disruptive via their breathing, then the solution of going into the back rows is a practical one. Or your "accidental" awakening of the student. Perfectly reasonable.
But, other than that, it's the student's own responsibility to stay awake. Students leaving your lecture is worse - and that happens, too, is ultimatively more disruptive and disconcerting - but maybe they have a shift, a parallel session, an emergency, or some other good reason to leave. It is a good idea to take anything that is below the threshold of intentionally and antagonistically disruptive on the chin.
A little tolerance goes a long way.

When my father taught Spanish literature in Brooklyn College at night, he would lower his voice if there was a sleeping student, so as to not deprive him/her of sleep!

"Who knows, maybe the student has a half-conscious way of absorbing information?"  This was me, my answer is posted here too!

@PhilFreedenberg That's a nice prof, I like that.

@AstorFlorida And that's why I believe in tolerance!

I agree that it is annoying and can cause you to lose your line of thought. It has happened to me a few times before, and you cannot "internally, in your mind" ignore it!
My usual approach, though, is to disregard it! Students occasionally work late shifts and are just exhausted. Once, when a student yawned loudly, I just remarked, "Amen to that!" in a lighthearted attempt not to make things awkward.
When I saw a student sleeping for the first time, I was upset but did nothing. After that, I looked at the student's grades, and he was doing really well! I therefore reasoned that perhaps he is simply exhausted and it is a work (or) athletic exhaustion issue.
I comment here from the same foreigner in the US prospective.

Disregarding it is a fine option, and the fact that @User1000234 recognizes it as an option is key. An analogous recognition is also available: describing it as “annoying” suggests that the annoyance is assumed to be intrinsic to the student’s behavior; instead, remind oneself that X is annoying is very different from I become [or permit myself to be or, more empowering yet, make myself] annoyed at X. Each of us owns, and even creates, their own attitudes. Our attitudes aren’t caused by others’ actions, but invented by us in response to those actions.

Many people have said he is likely not doing it on purpose, but it is also worth mentioning how you can help. Some of the best professors I've ever had took time to mention that they understood we had a lot going on, and if we needed to stand up to stay awake, they understood.  There were a couple of classes where I could not stay awake if I didn't stand up a couple times during the hour.
When I was a grad student and taught a class, I made to make sure to mention that on the first day of class. It was an early 8am class, I always had a couple students who would just stand up on the side or back of the classroom for a couple of minutes, then sit back down. It wasn't a disturbance and I actually felt better knowing they were trying to pay attention.

He might have sleep apnea; be mindful.

@Buzz The only question in OP is "What is a good course of action?". I'd argue "Be mindful (for reason X)." does provide an answer to that question. But I agree it is not a very good answer because it should elaborate more (like Llamageddon's answer) and/or try to address more points from the OP.

Apologies if I misspoke; I also have SA and it's not particularly pleasant being 'awoken' from sleep (which was where my 'be mindful' stemmed from), and I hadn't seen Llamageddon's post at that point.

You might want to announce to the whole class that if they are feeling tired that it is ok to stand up and move to the side/back of the room and remain standing until a break. It is very hard for most people to sleep while standing and better to hear the content than miss it entirely.

An announcement to the whole class is likely to be perceived by everyone in the class as a public shaming of this student, specifically. I don't think that's the intent of your answer, but it's a likely result, so I'd be careful about this course of action if it's not the intent.

Possible reasons for the student being excessively tired (not exhaustively)

Sleeping problems

Either for no particular reason at all (sometimes happens)
Or due to mental health problems
Or due to physical reasons, like sleep apnea


Stress or working late because of other courses
Stress from life (sickness or death of family member, having to move)
Went out to party last night
Having to work to support himself

Falling asleep rarely means the lecture is boring. Only point 4. is arguably disrespectful. If it keeps happening you could even consider asking what's up, the student could be struggling with any of the above.

Talk to the student about sleep apnea, and recommend him to get a sleep study. He sounds word-for-word like me back in school, and difficulty staying awake is a hallmark symptom of Sleep Apnea(and Sleep Disordered Breathing in general)
Loud/irregular breathing during sleep happens when the airway collapses, causing its tissues to vibrate, which is also the direct mechanism of how sleep apnea happens. He needs a sleep study, and to treat it, before it ruins his life.
Also consider things like medication that can make people sleepy, antihistamines a good example, but could be any medication.

I wouldn't recommend instructors try to diagnose their students with medical conditions, that seems quite inappropriate to me.

@BryanKrause I agree that instructors (and other unqualified people) shouldn't diagnose medical conditions, but I think it's quite reasonable for us (unqualified folks) to suggest possibilities that should be checked. A sleep study, recommended twice in this answer, is the usual way to check for sleep apnea. I think OP should consult a doctor and mention sleep apnea as something  to be considered (if the doctor doesn't mention it unprompted). (Full disclosure: I have sleep apnea and have benefited greatly from treatment.)

Try to open a window. Lack of oxygen is a very common cause of sleepiness, and stuffy rooms with many people often have low oxygen levels. Cracking a window open might conceivably be enough to fix the issue.
I remember a conference a few years ago. I was attending a talk in the afternoon, after a full day. It was in a medium sized room, which was packed, and I found it very hard to stay awake. What's worse, this was a talk on a subject I found fascinating. The speaker was doing a great job presenting it and I was really, honestly interested and absolutely wanted to follow. I still kept almost nodding off.
So apart from all the other absolutely valid possible reasons in other answers, it could also just be that the room's too stuffy. So try opening a window next time (assuming the weather and your building's heating allows it, freezing is also not conducive to learning) and see if that might solve the problem.

Perhaps you could wake them up without really disturbing them. You would need to know what situation they are in. I would talk to them after class and ask them what they are going through. Maybe someone died; maybe they are going through a break up; perhaps they are working around the clock and have no time to sleep. I would find out and find a better way to educate them. They are there for a reason. I would want to know why they are there.

How dare they fall asleep on me.

That’s a silly way to think about it.
I would want to know the situation. Ask and you shall receive.

Just ask the class (or just that student if you want to embarrass him) not to sleep.
I routinely slept in my courses (That's what they are for, after all  :).  Then one year I had a professor with a 'no sleeping' rule.  (It is understandable to feel offended if someone is sleeping while you talk.)  So I didn't sleep.
(I nodded off sometimes, and when that happened, the professor called me out on it.  "Hey sleepyhead, wake up!  No sleeping!"  Or something to that effect.)
If he keeps sleeping, after you told him that's not allowed, you fail him under the 'class participation' clause.  Your class, your rules.

I think it is not kind to tell off someone publicly for non-disruptive behaviour at academic level (and sleeping is one of these). If there are noises involved, it's a different story, but it's quite different handling from someone who talks into their phone during lecture.

It's not kind, but neither is sleeping in class.  It worked out, and made for some fun banter.  Y'all are criticizing something you've never tried or seen.

Why all the downvotes?  Its a common sense solution - just ask them.

What do you mean by "ask them"? Your suggestion is to (slightly) ridicule them, not ask them. I am certainly not in favour of the "snowflake" strategy to protect people from consequences of misdeeds at any cost, but I do not see why sleeping should incur ridicule. There are many reasons why people fall asleep. Maybe my opinion is coloured by Japan: even with their work ethic, someone falling  asleep is respected.

As funny as a "no sleeping" rule is, I think there is generally an implied no sleeping rule anyway. I doubt most students falling asleep in lectures are doing it deliberately.

Why is it funny?  You're clearly communicating your expectation.  Besides, most of the comments above seem to disagree.  They imply its normal, that an instructor shouldn't be bothered, and generally should be tolerated.

You actually studied in a place where a professor felt they had to have an explicit "no sleeping" rule? That feels as useful as having a "wearing clothes in class is obligatory" rule. Sure, any of us might doze off by accident, but surely everyone knows this is not OK and should be avoided.

"surely everyone knows" - but the question is what to do if someone doesn't know

I don't think the student believes it is OK to sleep. I mean, nobody in their right mind could actually believe it is OK to sleep during a lecture, and if they do, then we have a far, far more serious problem anyway. This is something that can indeed happen to anyone, but I really doubt anyone would do it believing it is not a problem.
